# Underline navigation menu CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have an underline when a link is hovered over. However, you'll notice that the underline doesn't sit flush with the line below it. Could someone explain or show me how to change this CSS to work so when the link is hovered, the 3px line sits on top of the 1px line spanning the page. Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.menu {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", verdana, arial; 
    position:fixed; 
    background:transparent;
    width:100%; 
    top:100px; 
    left:0; 
    height:25px;       /* decide on this as some stage */
    padding: 0;
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 600;  /* decide on this as some stage */
    padding-top: 10px;  /* decide on this as some stage */
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.ty-menu__items {
    position: absolute;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.ty-menu__item {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    }

a:link, a:visited {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: light;
    color: #494949;
    background: transparent;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

a:hover, a:active {
    background: transparent;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #494949; /* decide on this as some stage */
    color: #494949; /* decide on this as some stage */
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="menu">
<ul class="ty-menu__items">
  <li class="ty-menu__item"><a href="#home">home</a></li>
  <li class="ty-menu__item"><a href="#news">news</a></li>
  <li class="ty-menu__item"><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
  <li class="ty-menu__item"><a href="#about">about</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please upload a jsfiddle link to your source code

Comment: Sure. Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/rqu39zcf/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a padding-bottom to your hover, which appears to sit the 3px line on top of the 1px as you intended.

```
a:hover, a:active {
    padding-bottom:8px;
    background: transparent;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #494949; /* decide on this as some stage */
    color: #494949; /* decide on this as some stage */
}
```

Updated JS Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/rqu39zcf/1/

Comment: I swear i did that :O Thanks a lot though :D

Answer (score 0):

I changed it to this if I think I understand

```
.menu {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", verdana, arial; 
    position:fixed; 
    background:transparent;
    width:100%; 
    top:100px; 
    left:0; 
    height:35px;       /* decide on this as some stage */
    padding: 0;
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 600;  /* decide on this as some stage */
    padding-top: 10px;  /* decide on this as some stage */
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.ty-menu__items {
    position: absolute;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.ty-menu__item {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    }

a:link, a:visited {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: light;
    color: #494949;
    background: transparent;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

a:hover, a:active {
    padding-bottom:1px;
    background: transparent;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #494949; /* decide on this as some stage */
    color: #494949; /* decide on this as some stage */
}
```

namely I changed the .menu: height

Comment: That doesn't work. IT doesn't matter anyway. Someone has already given me the answer. Thanks though